# The Leibniz rule for the curl of the product of a scalar field and a vector field

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

I have some scalar field $u:D \rightarrow\mathbb R; \space \space D\subset \mathbb R^3$

and a vector field $\vec{v}: D\rightarrow \mathbb R^3$

and I want to show that:

> curl$(u\vec{v)}=$grad$(u)\times \vec{v}+u\space$rot$(\vec{v})$

My question is: How do I multiply a vector field by a scalar field?

Can I write curl$(u\vec{v})$ like this:

curl$(\vec{v})=$curl$\begin{pmatrix}uv_1\\uv_2\\uv_3\end{pmatrix}=$

$\begin{vmatrix}\hat{i}&\hat{j}&\hat{k}\\\frac{d}{dx}&\frac{d}{dy}&\frac{d}{dz}\\uv_1&uv_2&uv_3\end{vmatrix}=\hat{i}(\frac{d}{dy}(uv_3)-\frac{d}{dz}(uv_2))-\hat{j}(\frac{d}{dx}(uv_3)-\frac{d}{dz}(uv_1))+\hat{k}(\frac{d}{dx}(uv_2)-\frac{d}{dy}(uv_1))$

or am I doing something wrong?

**Edit:**

grad$(u)\times\vec{v}+u\space $curl$(\vec{v})=(\frac{du}{dx}\hat{i}+\frac{du}{dy}\hat{j}+\frac{du}{dz}\hat{k}) \times (v_1 \hat{i}+v_2\hat{j}+v_3\hat{k})+u\space $curl$(\vec{v})$

$=\hat{i}(\frac{du}{dy}(v_3)-\frac{du}{dz}(v_2))-\hat{j}(\frac{du}{dx}(v_3)-\frac{du}{dz}(v_1))+\hat{k}(\frac{du}{dx}(v_2)-\frac{du}{dy}(v_1))+u[\hat{i}(\frac{d}{dy}(v_3)-\frac{d}{dz}(v_2))-\hat{j}(\frac{d}{dx}(v_3)-\frac{d}{dz}(v_1))+\hat{k}(\frac{d}{dx}(v_2)-\frac{d}{dy}(v_1)]$

$\not=\hat{i}(\frac{d}{dy}(uv_3)-\frac{d}{dz}(uv_2))-\hat{j}(\frac{d}{dx}(uv_3)-\frac{d}{dz}(uv_1))+\hat{k}(\frac{d}{dx}(uv_2)-\frac{d}{dy}(uv_1))$

I guess I am making a mistake somewhere but I can't find it.

**Edit 2:**

grad$\space u \times \vec{v}=(\frac{du}{dx}\hat{i}+\frac{du}{dy}\hat{j}+\frac{du}{dz}\hat{k}) \times (v_1 \hat{i}+v_2\hat{j}+v_3\hat{k})$

$=\begin{vmatrix}\hat{i}&\hat{j}&\hat{k}\\\frac{du}{dx}&\frac{du}{dy}&\frac{du}{dz}\\v_1&v_2&v_3\end{vmatrix}=\hat{i}(\frac{du}{dy}(v_3)-\frac{du}{dz}(v_2))-\hat{j}(\frac{du}{dx}(v_3)-\frac{du}{dz}(v_1))+\hat{k}(\frac{du}{dx}(v_2)-\frac{du}{dy}(v_1))$

Comment: So far so good, but to be clear, each of the products is differentiated, i.e., the first term of the first parenthetical is $\frac{d}{dy}(u v_3)$.

Comment: @Travis Okay thanks. But then the identity seems to be false. I will post the rest of my calculation in my opening post. Maybe I made an error. Would be awesome if you could take a look at that too :)

Comment: I do think it's okay, though usually one would write the second term as $u\,\text{curl } {\bf v}$.

Comment: Yeah I made a mistake translating it. In german it is rot for rotation.

Comment: @Travis I added my calculation.

Comment: @Rzeta As of this moment, I can see an error in Line 2 of the edit.  In that line, there is no $u$ term; it disappeared.

Comment: @Dr.MV Do you mean this line? $\hat{i}(\frac{du}{dy}(v_3)-\frac{du}{dz}(v_2))-\hat{j}(\frac{du}{dx}(v_3)-\frac{du}{dz}(v_1))+\hat{k}(\frac{du}{dx}(v_2)-\frac{du}{dy}(v_1))$ Isn't the $u$ term included in the $\frac{du}{dx_i}$

Comment: Yes. The font was small on my screen and I missed that.  But, what happened to any cross product?

Comment: @Dr.MV I added another detailed calculation of the cross product in my opening post. Maybe this is where I made a mistake

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We will use the notation such that summations are implied over repeated indices.  SO, for example, $\vec A =\sum_{i=1}^3 \hat x_iA_i$ will be abbreviated $\vec A =\hat x_iA_i$.

$$\begin{align}
\nabla \times (u\vec v)&=\left(\hat x_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\right)\times(u\hat x_j v_j)\\\\
&=(\hat x_i \times \hat x_j)\frac{\partial (uv_j)}{\partial x_i}\\\\
&=(\hat x_i \times \hat x_j)\left(u\frac{\partial v_j}{\partial x_i}+v_j\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\right)\\\\
&=u\left(\hat x_i \frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}\right)\times  (\hat x_jv_j)+\left(\hat x_i \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\right)\times (\hat x_jv_j)\\\\
&=u\nabla \times \vec v+\nabla u \times \vec v
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks! Really nice solution. Much simpler and less crowded than mine. Can you still take a look at the calculation I just added. There seems to be a mistake but I can't find it.

Comment: You're welcome!  And as always, my pleasure.